# The color of the navlinks doesn't change even though the state changes to dark mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react for the first time, and I am facing this error. (Sorry for this mess of a code)

App.js

```
const btnMode = {
    lightBtn: <LightModeIcon style={{color: "white", marginRight: "1.25rem",}} />,
    darkBtn: <NightsStayIcon style={{color: "#395B64", marginRight: "1.25rem",}} />,
  }

const [linkStyle, setLinkStyle] = useState({
    color: "black",
  });
const [btnStyle, setBtnStyle] = useState(btnMode.darkBtn);

const themeHandler = () => {

if(btnStyle.type.type.render.displayName === "NightsStayIcon") //to change from light to dark mode
 {

setBtnStyle(btnMode.lightBtn);
setLinkStyle({
        color: "white !important",
      });
 }

else{

setBtnStyle(btnMode.darkBtn);
setLinkStyle({
        color: "black",
      });
 }
}

return(
<div className="App">
        <Header style={linkStyle}/>
        <div onClick={themeHandler}>
          { btnStyle }
        </div>
</div>
);
```

I sent the state of the linkStyle to Header component which should change accordingly to the state of the btnStyle.

Header.js

```
function Header(props) {
    console.log(props.style) // {color: "white !important"} when state changes accordingly
    const navLinks = [
        { id: 0, body: "Home", link: "/" },
        { id: 1, body: "About", link: "/about" },
        { id: 2, body: "Articles", link: "/articles" },
        { id: 3, body: "Social", link: "/social" },
        { id: 4, body: "Contact", link: "/contact" },
    ];
    return (
    <div className="navContent">
                {navLinks.map((item) => (
                    <a href={item.link} key={item.id} style={props.style}>
                        {item.body}
                    </a>
                ))}
            </div>
)
```

In *a* tag, I cant get the style required even though I can see that in the console, the property does reflect the state change. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the function themeHandler() when you want to change the theme.
ideally you should call this function as well whenever you want to switch to the theme.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the div which calls the themeHandler. I have added it in the code. It still doesn't change the link color accordingly

Comment: const btnMode = {
    lightBtn: <LightModeIcon style={{color: "white", marginRight: "1.25rem",}} onClick={()=>{setBtnStyle(btnMode.darkBtn),setLinkStyle({color: "black"})}} />,
    darkBtn: <NightsStayIcon style={{color: "#395B64", marginRight: "1.25rem",}} onClick={()=>{setBtnStyle(btnMode.lightBtn),setLinkStyle({color: "white !important"})}}/>
const [linkStyle, setLinkStyle] = useState({color: "black"});
const [btnStyle, setBtnStyle] = useState(btnMode.darkBtn);
return(
<div className="App">
        <Header style={linkStyle}/>
        <div>{ btnStyle }</div>
</div>
)

Comment: Please don't put blocks of code in comments; it's very difficult to read.